# Python - Notifying another thread blocked on subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, multiprocessing

I am creating a custom job scheduler with a web frontend in python 3.4 on linux. This program creates a daemon (consumer) thread that waits for jobs to come available in a PriorityQueue. These jobs can manually be added through the web interface which adds them to the queue. When the consumer thread finds a job, it executes a program using subprocess.run, and waits for it to finish.

The basic idea of the worker thread:

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, queue):
    self.queue = queue
    # more code here

def run(self):
    while True:
        try:
            job = self.queue.get()
            #do some work

            proc = subprocess.run("myprogram", timeout=my_timeout)
            #do some more things

        except TimeoutExpired:
            #do some administration
            self.queue.add(job)
```

However:

- This consumer should be able to receive some kind of signal from the frontend (main thread) that it should stop the current job and instead work on the next job in the queue (saving the state of the current job and adding it to the end of the queue again). This can (and will most likely) happen while blocked on subprocess.run().
- The subprocesses can simply be killed (the program that is executed saves sme state in a file) but the worker thread needs to do some administration on the killed job to make sure it can be resumed later on.
- There can be multiple such worker threads.
- Signal handlers are not an option (since they are always handled by the main thread which is a webserver and should not be bothered with this).
- Having an event loop in which the process actively polls for events (such as the child exiting, the timeout occurring or the interrupt event) is in this context not really a solution but an ugly hack. The jobs are performance-heavy and constant context switches are unwanted.

What synchronization primitives should I use to interrupt this thread or to make sure it waits for several events at the same time in a blocking fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've accidentally glossed over a simple solution: your second bullet point says that you have the ability to kill the programs that are running in subprocesses. Notice that `subprocess.call` [returns the return code of the subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). This means that you can let the main thread kill the subprocess, and just check the return code to see if you need to do any cleanup. Even better, you could use [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) instead, which will raise an exception for you if the returncode isn't 0. I don't know what platform you're working on, but on Linux, killed processes generally don't return a 0 if they're killed.

It could look something like this:

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, queue):
    self.queue = queue
    # more code here

def run(self):
    while True:
        try:
            job = self.queue.get()
            #do some work

            subprocess.check_call("myprogram", timeout=my_timeout)
            #do some more things

        except (TimeoutExpired, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
            #do some administration
            self.queue.add(job)
```

Note that if you're using Python 3.5, you can use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead, and set the `check` argument to `True`.

If you have a strong need to handle the cases where the worker needs to be interrupted when it *isn't* running the subprocess, then I think you're going to have to use a polling loop, because I don't think the behavior you're looking for is supported for threads in Python. You can use a [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.Event) object to pass the "stop working now" pseudo-signal from your main thread to the worker, and have the worker periodically check the state of that event object.

If you're willing to consider using multiple processing stead of threads, consider switching over to the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#), which would allow you to handle signals. There is more overhead to spawning full-blown subprocesses instead of threads, but you're essentially looking for signal-like asynchronous behavior, and I don't think Python's threading library supports anything like that. One benefit though, would be that you would be freed from the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf)(PDF link), so you may actually see some speed benefits if your worker processes (formerly threads) are doing anything CPU intensive.